# QR Decomposition for a rectangular matrix: What happens to the erased columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, the QR decomposition :
$$
A=QR
$$
produces an orthonormal matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and an upper triangular matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

In the case $m>n$, an Economy QR is derived by *cutting* the last $m-n$ columns the matrix $Q$ and for the matrix $R$, the last $m-n$ rows are basically $0$s so they will be removed as well and this produce the economy QR $$A=Q_{1}R_{1}$$
where $Q_{1}\in\mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ and $R_{1}\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$

My question is by removing the non-zero $m-n$ columns of $Q$ in this procedure aren't we removing some valuable data? Suppose $A$ is of full rank and I am working on a regression problem if $Q$ will hold valuable data features should I prioritize some of these features by multiplying $A$ (which would be holding the features) with a permutation matrix $P$ producing $PA=QR=Q_{1}R_{1}$? This would (correct me if I am wrong) interchange column $i$ with column $j$ of Q.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you suspect that multiplying by $P$ will have this effect, but I believe that you are wrong.

Comment: Do you know how to derive QR factorization?  (Over) Simplifying there's basically two ways: (1) Householder reflections or (2) Gram Schmitdt.  If you have a tall skinny $A$ with linearly independent columns and apply (2) then you get a tall skinny $Q$ with orthonormal columns (thin QR factorization).  Since the book-keeping for Gram Schmidt doesn't throw away any information about $A$, neither does thin $QR$ factorization.

Comment: If $A$ has full rank, the columns of $Q$ that are removed form a basis for the orthogonal  complement to the column space of $A$; when $A$ is rank deficient, these columns span a subspace of this orthogonal complement.

Comment: In a general polynomial regression problem where $A$ of full rank has a size $m\times (k+1)$ where $m>>k+1$ then the tall and skinny matrix is decomposed (by Householder Transformation) to an $m\times m$ matrix $Q$ and a matrix $R$ with last $m-n$ rows are $0$s. The very idea is that this large $m\times m$ $Q$ matrix has $m$ columns. The last $m-(k-1)$ columns of $Q$ will be removed to produce the economy version of $QR$ so if the last column of $Q$ (which will be removed) consists of vital information. I would multiply $A$ by $P$ to interchange rows of $A$ which would interchange columns of Q

Comment: @user8675309 So these removed columns of $Q$ don't have the same span of $A$?

Comment: Is the multiplication by $P$ seem reasonable in such case? @BenGrossmann

Comment: @R As reasonable as multiplying any two matrices; I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with this multiplication

Comment: @BenGrossmann $P$ is the permutation of the identity matrix thus multiplying it with $A$ would accomplish interchange rows $A$.

Comment: I will work on the Gram Schmidt and study the pattern of size of $A$ thank you @user8675309 and Ben :)

Comment: @R So why do you think that interchanging rows of $A$ results in rearranging the columns of $Q$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann To be honest it was a lucky guess, the span of $A$ must be the same as the span of $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct algebraic proof:

'Full' QR factorization
$A = Q'R'$

where $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is tall and skinny and is injective (full rank).
$Q'$ is orthogonal (and $m\times m$) but $R'$ is $m\times n$

implies 'thin' QR factorization
$A=QR$

$Q':=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} \mathbf q_1 &\cdots &  \mathbf q_{n} &  \mathbf q_{n+1} &\cdots & \mathbf q_{m}\end{array}\bigg]$

$Q:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c} \mathbf q_1 & \cdots &  \mathbf q_{n}\end{array}\bigg]$

$R'=\begin{bmatrix}R \\ \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf r_1^T\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf r_n^T \\ \mathbf 0^T \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf 0^T\end{bmatrix}$
where we know everything below $R$ is zero because $R'$ is 'upper triangular' (though tall and skinny)

Finally, using the 'outer product' interpretation of matrix multiplication this gives

$A=Q'R' = \big(\mathbf q_1\mathbf r_1^T + \cdots +\mathbf q_n\mathbf r_n^T\big) + \big(\mathbf q_{n+1}\mathbf 0^T+ \cdots +\mathbf q_{m}\mathbf 0^T\big)=\big(\mathbf q_1\mathbf r_1^T + \cdots +\mathbf q_n\mathbf r_n^T\big) = QR$

Comment: So it seems that through the block multiplication, $q_{n+1 : m}$ are multiplied with $0$s from the last $m-n$ rows of $R$ which makes things clear now. I have wrongly used the term "cutting" the columns

Comment: Yes. Two instructive follow-ups would be (i) do the derivation of 'thin' QR factorization using Gram Schmidt, and (ii) prove that 'thin' QR factorization is unique for injective $A$ (with the usual constraint that $R$ has positive diagonals).

Comment: Indeed and we can conclude from this that the last $m-n$ columns of $Q$ form a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(A)^{\perp}$ since $q(n+1:m)*R(n+1 : m,:)=0$ this means that any valuable data would already be in the $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ and not in its complement