# Understanding this matrix expansion

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

EDIT:  *With help from user8675309, it seems the answer to my question is that $Q$ and $R$ are obtained from a reduced $QR$ decomposition, not a full one. As a consequence, $R$ is a square matrix, and $Q^\top Q = I$ but $QQ^\top \neq I$. This resolves my question below.*

In my current studies, I have come across the following reformulation:

$$I - A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top = I - QQ^\top \tag{1}$$

where $A$ is a $N\times D$ matrix, I is the $N\times N$ identity matrix, and $Q$ is obtained from the QR decomposition of $A$, i.e.: $QR=A$.

Below are my attempts to follow this derivation.

First off, I assume I may not directly invert $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ as $(A^\top A)^{-1}=A^{-1}A^{-\top}$ because $A$ is not square. If I were allowed to do this, the RHS of Equation 1 would become $I$ and the entire term would be zero. Correct?

So I believe we instead make use of the QR decomposition. Plugging the $QR=A$ into the LHS of equation 1 yields:

$$I - QR((QR)^\top QR)^{-1}(QR)^\top$$

Expanding the tranpose yields:

$$I - QR(R^\top Q^\top QR)^{-1}R^\top Q^\top$$

Since [$Q$ is an orthogonal matrix](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eyanovsky/Teaching/Math151B/handouts/GramSchmidt.pdf) (*edit: I initially assumed the QR decomposition was a full decomposition*), we have $Q^\top Q=I$, which yields:

$$I - QR(R^\top R)^{-1}R^\top Q^\top$$

Now if I were to invert $R^\top R$ as $(R^\top R)^{-1}=R^{-1}R^{-\top}$ I would obtain:

$$I - QRR^{-1}R^{-\top}R^\top Q^\top$$

which, using the identities $RR^{-1}=I$ and $R^{-\top}R^\top=I$ yields the RHS of equation 1:

$$I - Q Q^\top$$

**Now my question**: It seems to me that I am allowed to invert $(R^\top R)^{-1}$ but not $(A^\top A)^{-1}$. Why? Neither matrix appears to be square. Does this have anything to do with the fact that $R$ is upper triangular and $A$ is generally not?

Comment: what is "the QR Decomposition of A"?  Is it 'full' or 'thin' QR decompositon.  Iit seems that $A$ is tall and skinny, implied though not explicitly stated, and you are using 'thin' QR decomposition.  This is contradicted by your later claim that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix... but if that is true $I-QQ^T = \mathbf 0$ which in general is another contradiction.  For a detailed look at difference between 'thin' and 'full' QR factorization, here is a thread from yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202523/qr-decomposition-for-a-rectangular-matrix-what-happens-to-the-erased-columns/

Comment: @user8675309: Ooooh, yes, that seems to be the explanation! If I use a "thin"/reduced QR decomposition, then R is square. Thank you! I also made a small mistake above: If I use a reduced QR decomposition, then $Q^\top Q = I$ but $QQ^\top \neq I$. I have corrected this in the question.

Comment: You have not corrected the main problem.  Your post still says "Since  is an orthogonal matrix".  There is only one algebraic definition of an orthogonal matrix. That is the transpose of said matrix is its inverse.  Inverses commute (and imply being square) so you still have $I=Q^TQ = Q^{-1}Q=QQ^{-1} = QQ^T$ which gives the same contradiction.

Comment: I could not correct this mistake without answering my own question, so I have made some further edits to the question above for clarification. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you've resolved the question go ahead and drop in the rationale as an official answer and mark it as accepted.  Believe it or not this will likely be helpful to others in the future.